# Local edit file didn't work with pip

Tags: pip, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to install a local lib on project_name_1, but it is not working

```
pip install -e ~/Projects/Work_Projects/BP/project_name_2#egg=test
```

but I got the following problem

```
/home/infinity/Projects/Work_Projects/BP/project_name_2#egg=test should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
```

I think my problem is `#egg=test`, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory containing your `setup.py` file, and then use:

```
pip install -e .
```

(notice the dot, `.`, at the end). Then install any development requirements

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```